# Slicing problem with line project in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I have been, up to now, successfully using the line project to slice my mesh so its flat for the print bed. However, for this model I have getting this "flat area" mesh.You can see it when I rotate the model towards end of gif. Not sure how to avoid this...any tips?

Note: the mesh was created from a displace modifier with a voronoi texture. It has worked previously for other displace modifier/voronoi meshes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look carefully, you will note, that description of the tool says that it projects vertexes on plane, so all geometry is flattened, not (as you said) "sliced". If you want to cut, better use Box trim tool, which "cuts" or "slices"

Comment: Thanks for the correction!